# How can one search Gnome-Calendar notes?

Tags: search, gnome-calendar

I am running Gnome Calendar 41.2 in my Ubuntu 22.04.
Sometime in the last 2 years I made a note under one of my calendar entries that I am looking for. I know the name I am looking for but do not know how one can search Calendar for this particular entry (given that I have the name in the notes section but not in the heading of that date-entry).
Can anyone help?  I would like to emphasize that the name I am looking for is in the notes section but not in the main heading of the date entry.
Many thanks, Duncan

Comment: From a little experimenting I believe with the search bar, you can only find text in entry titles (not descriptions), and only in entries that are in the future. A more fruitful way would be to do a `grep` of the name on the calender file `~/.local/share/evolution/calendar/system/calendar.ics`.

Comment: Thank you very much - grep did the trick. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jos outlines above - the Gnome Calendar cannot be searched via the search bar. However, as Jos points out, doing a grep fo the name on the calendar file ~/.local/share/evolution/calendar/system/calendar.ics worked nicely.